# How do you make div elements display inline?

Tags: html, css

Given this HTML:

```
<div>foo</div><div>bar</div><div>baz</div>
```

How do you make them display inline like this:

> foo bar baz

not like this:

> foo
>   bar
>   baz

Comment: more easy way: HTML: <div>a</div> <div>b</div> <div>c</div> CSS: div { display: inline; }

Answer (score 295, accepted):

That's something else then:

```css
div.inline { float:left; }
.clearBoth { clear:both; }
```

```html
<div class="inline">1<br />2<br />3</div>
<div class="inline">1<br />2<br />3</div>
<div class="inline">1<br />2<br />3</div>
<br class="clearBoth" /><!-- you may or may not need this -->
```

Comment: actually this was the only way i found to display inline correctly i don't know why the no-float solution did not work....

Comment: The css class names here should not be used as an example. Use proper semantic naming like: http://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/

Comment: `float` is also the wrong method for this. `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` is the proper solution, or use an entire layout solution like flexbox. `float` is for wrapping text around images.

Answer (score 303):

An inline div is a freak of the web & should be beaten until it becomes a span (at least 9 times out of 10)...

```
<span>foo</span>
<span>bar</span>
<span>baz</span>
```

...answers the original question...

Comment: There are times when you want divs to display inline, for example, when you want to add a margin on the left and right of an element. I don't think that can be done with a span. Steve should probably be using float instead of inline though.

Comment: Not sure I follow Darryl, you can add margin or padding to a span>> <span style="color:white;background-color:black;margin:10px;padding:20px;">xxxxx</span>

Comment: What about wanting to have a div with background image flow inline within a paragraph of text. It is often more desirable to use a div with bg image set via CSS than to use an img tag.

Comment: `border:solid` doesn't work well with spans. If you want two pictures to display on the same level and have a border this is not suitable.

Comment: Unfortunately, HTML5 does not support putting a div inside a <span>. I used to use <span>s to put CSS styles on a section and not have the browser interpret the section as a block and force its block layout on me. But I just discovered today while porting my page to JQuery Mobile+HTML5 that if you have a <div> within a <span> the HTML5 validator will complain that it is invalid HTML5 so there are cases where using the <span> tag instead of an inline <div> is not feasible, at least with HTML5.

Comment: ...actually it doesn't answer the original question, which included "Given this HTML".

Comment: Sometimes though you are living in a world you didn't create and the only thing you can change in the CSS. In that case style="display: inline" works nicely.

Comment: If you are not 'stuck' with using divs this is a good answer. But there may be lots of reasons why you need to use divs but need them to appear as inline elements.

Comment: "inline div is a freak of the web & should be beaten until it becomes a span" - why?

Answer (score 202):

Try writing it like this:

```css
div { border: 1px solid #CCC; }
```

```html
    <div style="display: inline">a</div>
    <div style="display: inline">b</div>
    <div style="display: inline">c</div>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question, but considering the accepted answer, I suspect the question doesn't address the real scenario.

Comment: more easy way:
HTML:
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>

CSS:
div { 
  display: inline;
}

Answer (score 36):

Having read this question and the answers a couple of times, all I can do is assume that there's been quite a bit of editing going on, and my suspicion is that you've been given the incorrect answer based on not providing enough information. My clue comes from the use of `br` tag.

**Apologies to Darryl. I read class="inline" as style="display: inline". You have the right answer, even if you do use semantically questionable class names ;-)**

The miss use of `br` to provide structural layout rather than for textual layout is far too prevalent for my liking.

If you're wanting to put more than inline elements inside those `divs` then you should be floating those `div`s rather than making them inline.

Floated divs:

```
===== ======= ==   **** ***** ******   +++++ ++++
===== ==== =====   ******** ***** **   ++ +++++++
=== ======== ===   ******* **** ****   
===== ==== =====                       +++++++ ++
====== == ======
```

Inline divs:

```
====== ==== ===== ===== == ==== *** ******* ***** ***** 
**** ++++ +++ ++ ++++ ++ +++++++ +++ ++++
```

If you're after the former, then this is your solution and lose those `br` tags:

```
<div style="float: left;" >
  <p>block level content or <span>inline content</span>.</p>
  <p>block level content or <span>inline content</span>.</p>
</div>
<div style="float: left;" >
  <p>block level content or <span>inline content</span>.</p>
  <p>block level content or <span>inline content</span>.</p>
</div>
<div style="float: left;" >
  <p>block level content or <span>inline content</span>.</p>
  <p>block level content or <span>inline content</span>.</p>
</div>
```

note that the width of these divs is fluid, so feel free to put widths on them if you want to control the behavior.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 25):

Use `display:inline-block` with a margin and media query for IE6/7:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      div { display:inline-block; }
      /* IE6-7 */
      @media,
          {
          div { display: inline; margin-right:10px; }
          }
   </style>
  </head>
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>bar</div>
  <div>baz</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 17):

> You should use `<span>` instead of `<div>` for correct way of
>   **inline**. because div is a block level element, and your requirement is for inline-block level elements.

Here is html code as per your requirements :

```
<div class="main-div">
 <div>foo</div>
 <div>bar</div>
 <div>baz</div>`
</div>
```

### You've two way to do this

---

- using simple `display:inline-block;`
- or using `float:left;`

so you've to change display property `display:inline-block;` forcefully

**Example one**

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Example two**

```
div {
    float: left;
}
```

> you need to clear float

```
.main-div:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned, display:inline is probably what you want.  Some browsers also support inline-blocks.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inlineblock

Comment: @NexusRex there is work around to get IE to behave correctly however display:inline is the correct answer.  I believe the work around is:

display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
*zoom: 1;

setting zoom forces IE to treat the element like a block element.

Answer (score 7):

Just use a wrapper div with "float: left" and put boxes inside also containing float: left:

CSS:

```
wrapperline{
width: 300px;
float: left;
height: 60px;
background-color:#CCCCCC;}

.boxinside{
width: 50px;
float: left;
height: 50px;
margin: 5px;
background-color:#9C0;
float:left;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapperline">
<div class="boxinside">Box 1</div>
<div class="boxinside">Box 1</div>
<div class="boxinside">Box 1</div>
<div class="boxinside">Box 1</div>
<div class="boxinside">Box 1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

ok, for me :

```
<style type="text/css">
    div{
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width:25px;
        height:25px;
    }
</style>
<div>toto</div>
<div>toto</div>
<div>toto</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

`<span>` ?

Comment: I think we are talking about inlining block elements that can have width and height. Imagine a div with a background image that you want to flow inline with text.

Answer (score 4):

```
<style type="text/css">
div.inline { display:inline; }
</style>
<div class="inline">a</div>
<div class="inline">b</div>
<div class="inline">c</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I know people say this is a terrible idea, but it can in practice be useful if you want to do something like tile images with comments underneath them.  e.g. Picasaweb uses it to display the thumbnails in an album.
See for example/demo http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/inline_block_quirks.html ( class goog-inline-block ; I abbreviate it to ib here )

```
/* below is a set of hacks to make inline-block work right on divs in IE. */
html > body .ib { display:inline-block; }
.ib {display:inline-block;position:relative;}
* html .ib { display: inline; }
:first-child + html .ib { display:inline; }
```

Given that CSS, set your div to class ib, and now it's magically an inline block element.

Answer (score 4):

I would use spans or float the div left. The only problem with floating is that you have to clear the float afterwards or the containing div must have the overflow style set to auto

Comment: I believe we are talking about a div inline with text or other, not floated to one side.

Comment: When using float: left, with overflow: auto on the containing div, how/when would the scrollbar that the overflow could come into play?

Answer (score 3):

You need to contain the three divs. Here is an example:

**CSS**

```
div.contain
{
  margin:3%;
  border: none;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}

div.contain div
{
  display:inline;
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  border:1px solid red;
  background-color:#fffff7;
  -moz-border-radius:25px; /* Firefox */
  border-radius:25px;
}
```

Note: border-radius attributes are optional and only work in CSS3 compliant browsers.

**HTML**

```
<div class="contain">
  <div>Foo</div>
</div>

<div class="contain">
  <div>Bar</div>
</div>

<div class="contain">
  <div>Baz</div>
</div>
```

Note that the divs 'foo' 'bar' and 'baz' are each held within the 'contain' div.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this way without using any CSS -

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>baz</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Right now you are using block-level elements that way you are getting an unwanted result. So you can you inline elements like span, small etc.

```
<span>foo</span><span>bar</span><span>baz</span>
```

Comment: No , in tr should be two td

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. I was working with bootstrap and I wanted to have radio buttons inline:

```
                <div class="form-group form-inline-radio">
                    <div class="form-check form-radio-outline form-radio-primary mb-3">
                        <input type="radio" name="formRadio4" id="formRadio4" checked="" class="form-check-input">
                        <label for="formRadio4" class="form-check-label"> Radio Outline Warning </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-radio-outline form-radio-primary mb-3">
                        <input type="radio" name="formRadio4" id="formRadio4" checked="" class="form-check-input">
                        <label for="formRadio4" class="form-check-label"> Radio Outline Warning </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.form-inline-radio {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.form-check {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can do this like

```
.left {
    float:left;
    margin:3px;
}
<div class="left">foo</div>
<div class="left">bar</div>
<div class="left">baz</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="cdiv">
<div class="inline"><p>para 1</p></div>
 <div class="inline">
     <p>para 1</p>
     <span>para 2</span>
     <h1>para 3</h1>
</div>
 <div class="inline"><p>para 1</p></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f8L0y5wx/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>foo</div><div>bar</div><div>baz</div>
//solution 1
<style>
    #div01, #div02, #div03 {
                                float:left;
                                width:2%;
    }   
 </style>
 <div id="div01">foo</div><div id="div02">bar</div><div id="div03">baz</div>

 //solution 2

 <style>
      #div01, #div02, #div03 {
                                  display:inline;
                                  padding-left:5px;
      }   
</style>
<div id="div01">foo</div><div id="div02">bar</div><div id="div03">baz</div>

 /* I think this would help but if you have any other thoughts just let me knw      kk */
```

Answer (score -1):

I just tend to make them fixed widths so that they add up to the total width of the page - probably only works if you are using a fixed width page. Also "float".