# Making a <div> element without a newline before it?

Tags: css

Here's my code:

```
Your rating: <div>4</div>
```

It looks like:

```
Your rating:
     4
```

How can I make a div not make a newline before it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<div style="display:inline-block">4</div>
```

or

```
<div style="display:inline">4</div>
```

It really depends on how you want to use the div container. It might even be more practical (for the latter example) to use a span if you do not want a block element.

Answer (score 5):

Though you can use a <div> to do that, most people would recommend you use a <span> instead.

Answer (score 1):

Make it a `<span>4</span>`

OR

Wrap it with natural HTML `<em>`, `<strong>`, and style that child accordingly.

`#mypost strong {...}`

http://css-tricks.com/css-beginner-mistakes-1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your div display "inline" instead of the default "block". Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224602/how-do-you-make-divs-display-inline).

Answer (score 0):

DIV is block level element by default. You can add style='display:inline' to display in one line. or u can use Span or Label tag instead of DIV

Answer (score 0):

you can use span

```html
Your rating: <span>4</span
```

OP: Your rating: 4