# html display div in same line

Tags: jsp, html

I wish to display a text on my jsp page:

```
Sample date: <div id="sampleDate"/>
```

So I want it to be displayed as `Sample date: 29-Aug-2012`

But it is coming up like this:

`Sample Date:`

`29-Aug-2012`

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you make div elements display inline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224602/how-do-you-make-div-elements-display-inline)

Comment: @lc, not really a duplicate, as the old question revolves around a case where `div` elements contain blocks of text (not evident from the question, but from the discussion and answer acceptance).

Comment: Understand why is that new line too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements :)

Comment: Your markup is most probably not `<div id="sampleDate"/>`, as it would be just a start tag in HTML and an empty element in XHTML served as XHTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write it as -

```
Sample date: <span id="sampleDate"></span>
```

I won't recommend this but still if you want to keep DIV then you have to make it inline element -

```
Sample date: <div id="sampleDate"></div>

#sampleDate{ display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 2):

css for sampleDate should be

```
#sampleDate { 
   display:inline;
}
```

Also you could use `float:left;` for Sample date: and for #sampleDate block `float:right;`
put both blocks inside other block and set width ( then there wont be a huge space between these two )

Comment: The first part is the correct answer to the question asked. It would be pointless to play with floats in a simple case like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `​#sampleDate{display:inline;}​`. But you should use @Dipaks method, by using a span tag.

View live here http://jsfiddle.net/WkNp8/1/