# How can I display two asp:Panel controls side by side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have two panels. I want to show them abreast, but they don't.

## .aspx:

```
<asp:Panel ID="treeviewMenu" Width="20%" Height="500" runat="server" ScrollBars="Both" HorizontalAlign="Left">
    <asp:TreeView ID="treeview" runat="server" ShowLines="True" ImageSet="XPFileExplorer" OnSelectedNodeChanged="treeview_SelectedNodeChanged">
    </asp:TreeView>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="qvObjektMenu" Width="75%" Height="500" runat="server"  HorizontalAlign="Right">
    <asp:Table runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Right">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Label runat="server">
                    QVObjekt Id:
                </asp:Label>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Label ID="qvObjektId" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
</asp:Panel>
```

I have used a table outside this two elements, another Panel around them, nothing works.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: `asp:Panel` translates into a `div` which is a block level html element by default, this forces them to align on top of each other. You need to override that behaviour by surrounding them with a positioned `span` `display: inline-block; position: relative;` element or turn them into inline-block elements themselves.

Comment: you mean this <div style="like you said"><asp:panel></asp:panel><asp:panel></asp:panel></div>, that is not working

Comment: You can add the `style="display: inline-block;"` directly to your `asp:Panel`s if you want. You'd need 2 elements surrounding each `asp:Panel` if you do it the other way. Jeffrey Blake has given you an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer here is CSS. There are a few options for how to do it in CSS.

### Option 1: `display:inline-block;`

One option for that css is to use `display: inline-block;`:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .inlineBlock { display: inline-block; }
</style>
```

Coupled with setting it in the `<asp:Panel ...>` tags:

```
<asp:Panel ID="treeviewMenu" ... CssClass="inlineBlock">
    ...
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="qvObjektMenu" ... CssClass="inlineBlock">
    ...
</asp:Panel>
```

### Option 2a: `float:left;`

Another option, as mentioned in [Wim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16544480/259014) is to use floats. But I do not think you want to combine both panels to have floats -- I suspect you only want one or the other. Either:

```
<style type="text/css">
.floatLeft { float: left; }
</style>
```

And

```
<asp:Panel ID="treeviewMenu" ... CssClass="floatLeft">
    <asp:TreeView ID="treeview" runat="server" ShowLines="True" ImageSet="XPFileExplorer" >
    </asp:TreeView>
</asp:Panel>
```

(with the other panel as it currently is in your markup)

OR

### Option 2b: `float:right;`

```
<style type="text/css">
.floatRight { float: right; }
</style>
```

And

```
 <asp:Panel ID="qvObjektMenu" ... CssClass="floatRight">
    ...
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Panels will be rendered as `DIV` elements so using css `float:left`, `float:right` and `margin` should work.

Comment: also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224602/how-do-you-make-div-elements-display-inline/224626#224626