# Div's are not displaying corretly in IE8

Tags: css

Below code not display correcty in IE8.

They display correctly in Chrome, what is the problem ?

```
<div style="float: left;" >
  <p>block level content or <span>inline content</span>.</p>
  <p>block level content or <span>inline content</span>.</p>
</div>
<div style="float: left;" >
  <p>block level content or <span>inline content</span>.</p>
  <p>block level content or <span>inline content</span>.</p>
</div>
<div style="float: left;" >
  <p>block level content or <span>inline content</span>.</p>
  <p>block level content or <span>inline content</span>.</p>
</div>
```

There is no CSS except what is configured as part of div.
This code is from answer given by 'Steve Perks' for question [How do you make div elements display inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224602/how-do-you-make-div-elements-display-inline)

IE8 :

[image]

Chrome :

[image]

Comment: You might want to set a width on the div. It is probably assuming width 100%

Comment: @Marcin please see question edit

Answer (score 0):

Set appropriate CSS such that more than one div fits on each line, e.g. `width: 33%;`