# Why the only child element of inline container could still have line break?

Tags: html, css

This is the code I am referring to.

```
<div id="left" style="display: inline;">1</div>
<div id="right" style="display: inline;">
  <div id="inner">2</div>
</div>
```

I noticed the #inner div element would still have line break, so that put #right and #inner underneath #left.

I was expecting #left, #right and #inner all at the same line, since I marked both #left and #right as inline. It seems #inner could see to its parent layers, that there is the #left element next to it, even though #inner is really inside #right.

Why is browser behaving like this? **Shouldn't the browser separate the scope, and make #inner not see the outside world?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224602/how-do-you-make-div-elements-display-inline

Comment: This question is not the same as the /224602. This question is about inside elements placing with line break, even though there is really no element next to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#inner` div is still displayed as a block.  By default, blocks take an entire line to themselves.  In essence, the `#inner` div is making its inline parent stretch until it "comes" to the left and right edges of the latter's container.  This behavior is expected.

Instead of setting `display` of `#left` and `#right` as `inline`, set it as `inline-block`.  This declaration will make these divs wrap around the content of their children.

Here's the fiddle that shows that: http://jsfiddle.net/22Zvs/.

```
body > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `#inner` inherits the base div style of `display: block;` that all divs have. This style is from the User Agent Stylesheet generated by your browser when it interprets your website ( The interpretation can be different between browsers ) . So although its parent is using display inline, is not inherited by the child element. You can confirm this by using dev tools and inspecting the element to see this base style:

```
div {
   display: block;
}
```

The parent div essentially molds to shape of the child, thus giving you that line break.

---

Solution if you want it:

You can use a separate style sheet and use `display: inline;` like so:

css:

```
div {display: inline;}
```

html:

```
<div id="left">1</div>
<div id="right">
  <div id="inner">2</div>
</div>
```

if you dont want to include an external style sheet you can include it in the `head` tag:

```
<head>
  <style>
    div {display: inline;}
  </style>
</head>
```

example in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LW7Ly/

Comment: I know how to make them all inline. The question is about why, not about how.

Comment: @user926958 I don't believe I deserve the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Why is browser behaving like this?"*

Because the inner div element is still a block element, so by default it starts on a new line.

Rather than specifying the `display:inline` style with an inline `style=""` attribute, give those elements a class:

```
<div id="left" class="inline">1</div>
<div id="right" class="inline">
  <div id="inner">2</div>
</div>
```

...and then in your stylesheet define both elements with that class *and* div elements that are descendants of that class as being inline:

```
.inline, .inline div { display: inline; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k4CCs/

Or of course if you just want every div on the page to be inline you don't need the `class` or `style` attributes, you can just do this in your stylesheet:

```
div { display: inline; }
```