# How do I display my RSS feed horizontally?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display my custom RSS feed as a horizontal list. I am using a responsive template and embedding my feeds into that template. I believe that my JavaScript is not separating each RSS post into a separate list item like I thought it would.

```
    (function($) {
  "use strict";

  var RSS = function(target, url, options, callback) {
    this.target       = target
    this.url          = url
    this.html         = []
    this.effectQueue  = []

    this.options = $.extend({
      ssl: false,
      limit: null,
      key: null,
      layoutTemplate: '<ul style="display:inline-block;">{entries}</ul>',
      entryTemplate: '<li><a href="{url}"><div class="title">{title}</div></a><br /><author>{author}</author><img src="{teaserImageUrl}"></img><date>{date}</date><br />{shortBodyPlain}</li>',
      tokens: {

          },
      outputMode: 'json',
      dateFormat: 'MMM Do, YYYY',
      effect: 'show',
      offsetStart: false,
      offsetEnd: false,
      error: function() {
        console.log("jQuery RSS: url doesn't link to RSS-Feed");
      },
      onData: function(){},
      success: function(){}
    }, options || {})

    this.callback = callback || this.options.success
  }

  RSS.htmlTags = ["doctype", "html", "head", "title", "base", "link", "meta", "style", "script", "noscript", "body", "article", "nav", "aside", "section", "header", "footer", "h1-h6", "hgroup", "address", "p", "hr", "pre", "blockquote", "ol", "ul", "li", "dl", "dt", "dd", "figure", "figcaption", "div", "table", "caption", "thead", "tbody", "tfoot", "tr", "th", "td", "col", "colgroup", "form", "fieldset", "legend", "label", "input", "button", "select", "datalist", "optgroup", "option", "textarea", "keygen", "output", "progress", "meter", "details", "summary", "command", "menu", "del", "ins", "img", "iframe", "embed", "object", "param", "video", "audio", "source", "canvas", "track", "map", "area", "a", "em", "strong", "i", "b", "u", "s", "small", "abbr", "q", "cite", "dfn", "sub", "sup", "time", "code", "kbd", "samp", "var", "mark", "bdi", "bdo", "ruby", "rt", "rp", "span", "br", "wbr"]

  RSS.prototype.load = function(callback) {
    var apiProtocol = "http" + (this.options.ssl ? "s" : "")
      , apiHost     = apiProtocol + "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load"
      , apiUrl      = apiHost + "?v=1.0&output=" + this.options.outputMode + "&callback=?&q=" + encodeURIComponent(this.url)

    // set limit to offsetEnd if offset has been set
    if(this.options.offsetStart && this.options.offsetEnd) this.options.limit = this.options.offsetEnd;
    if (this.options.limit != null) apiUrl += "&num=" + this.options.limit;
    if (this.options.key != null)   apiUrl += "&key=" + this.options.key;

    $.getJSON(apiUrl, callback)
  }

  RSS.prototype.render = function() {
    var self = this

    this.load(function(data) {
      try {
        self.feed    = data.responseData.feed
        self.entries = data.responseData.feed.entries
      } catch(e) {
        self.entries = []
        self.feed    = null
        return self.options.error.call(self)
      }

      var html = self.generateHTMLForEntries()

      self.target.append(html.layout)

      if (html.entries.length !== 0) {
        $.isFunction(self.options.onData) && self.options.onData.call(self);
        self.appendEntriesAndApplyEffects($("entries", html.layout), html.entries);
      }

      if (self.effectQueue.length > 0) {
        self.executeEffectQueue(self.callback)
      } else {
        $.isFunction(self.callback) && self.callback.call(self);
      }
    })
  }

  RSS.prototype.appendEntriesAndApplyEffects = function(target, entries) {
    var self = this

    $.each(entries, function(idx, entry) {
      var $html = self.wrapContent(entry)

      if(self.options.effect === 'show') {
        target.before($html)
      } else {
        $html.css({ display: 'none' })
        target.before($html)
        self.applyEffect($html, self.options.effect)
      }
    })

    target.remove()
  }

  RSS.prototype.generateHTMLForEntries = function() {
    var self   = this
      , result = {
          entries: [],
          layout:  null
        }

    $(this.entries).each(function() {
      var entry = this,
          offsetStart = self.options.offsetStart,
          offsetEnd = self.options.offsetEnd;
      // offset required
      if(offsetStart && offsetEnd) {
        if(index >= offsetStart && index <= offsetEnd) {
            if(self.isRelevant(entry, result.entries)) {
                var evaluatedString = self.evaluateStringForEntry(self.options.entryTemplate, entry)
                result.entries.push(evaluatedString)
            }
        }
      }else{
      // no offset
        if(self.isRelevant(entry, result.entries)) {
            var evaluatedString = self.evaluateStringForEntry(self.options.entryTemplate, entry)
            result.entries.push(evaluatedString)
        }
      }
    })

    if(!!this.options.entryTemplate) {
      // we have an entryTemplate
      result.layout = this.wrapContent(this.options.layoutTemplate.replace("{entries}", "<entries></entries>"))
    } else {
      // no entryTemplate available
      result.layout = this.wrapContent("<div><entries></entries></div>")
    }

    return result
  }

  RSS.prototype.wrapContent = function(content) {
    if($.trim(content).indexOf('<') !== 0) {
      // the content has no html => create a surrounding div
      return $("<div>" + content + "</div>")
    } else {
      // the content has html => don't touch it
      return $(content)
    }
  }

  RSS.prototype.applyEffect = function($element, effect, callback) {
    var self = this

    switch(effect) {
      case 'slide':
        $element.slideDown('slow', callback)
        break
      case 'slideFast':
        $element.slideDown(callback)
        break
      case 'slideSynced':
        self.effectQueue.push({ element: $element, effect: 'slide' })
        break
      case 'slideFastSynced':
        self.effectQueue.push({ element: $element, effect: 'slideFast' })
        break
    }
  }

  RSS.prototype.executeEffectQueue = function(callback) {
    var self = this

    this.effectQueue.reverse()

    var executeEffectQueueItem = function() {
      var item = self.effectQueue.pop()

      if(item) {
        self.applyEffect(item.element, item.effect, executeEffectQueueItem)
      } else {
        callback && callback()
      }
    }

    executeEffectQueueItem()
  }

  RSS.prototype.evaluateStringForEntry = function(string, entry) {
    var result = string
      , self   = this

    $(string.match(/(\{.*?\})/g)).each(function() {
      var token = this.toString()
      result = result.replace(token, self.getValueForToken(token, entry))
    })

    return result
  }

  RSS.prototype.isRelevant = function(entry, entries) {
    var tokenMap = this.getTokenMap(entry)

    if(this.options.filter) {
      if(this.options.filterLimit && (this.options.filterLimit == entries.length)) {
        return false
      } else {
        return this.options.filter(entry, tokenMap)
      }
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }

  RSS.prototype.getTokenMap = function(entry) {
    if (!this.feedTokens) {
      var feed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.feed))
      delete feed.entries
      this.feedTokens = feed
    }

    return $.extend({
      feed:      this.feedTokens,
      url:       entry.link,
      author:    entry.author,
      date:      moment(entry.publishedDate).format(this.options.dateFormat),
      title:     entry.title,
      body:      entry.content,
      shortBody: entry.contentSnippet,

      bodyPlain: (function(entry) {
        var result = entry.content
          .replace(/<script[\\r\\\s\S]*<\/script>/mgi, '')
          .replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '')

        for(var i = 0; i < RSS.htmlTags.length; i++) {
          result = result.replace(new RegExp('<' + RSS.htmlTags[i], 'gi'), '')
        }

        return result
      })(entry),

      shortBodyPlain: entry.contentSnippet.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, ''),
      //shortBodyPlain: entry.contentSnippet.replace("-- Delivered by Feed43 service", ""),
      shortBodyPlain: entry.contentSnippet.replace("369gopee", "<author>").replace("321gopee", "</author><br />"),
      index:          $.inArray(entry, this.entries),
      totalEntries:   this.entries.length,

      teaserImage:    (function(entry){
        try { return entry.content.match(/(<img.*?>)/gi)[0] }
        catch(e) { return "" }
      })(entry),

      teaserImageUrl: (function(entry) {
        try { return entry.content.match(/(<img.*?>)/gi)[0].match(/src="(.*?)"/)[1] }
        catch(e) { return "" }
      })(entry)
    }, this.options.tokens)
  }

  RSS.prototype.getValueForToken = function(_token, entry) {
    var tokenMap = this.getTokenMap(entry)
      , token    = _token.replace(/[\{\}]/g, '')
      , result   = tokenMap[token]

    if(typeof result != 'undefined')
      return ((typeof result == 'function') ? result(entry, tokenMap) : result)
    else
      throw new Error('Unknown token: ' + _token)
  }

  $.fn.rss = function(url, options, callback) {
    new RSS(this, url, options, callback).render()
    return this; //implement chaining
  }

})(jQuery)
```

When I view the page source, there is not dynamically created html. How would I display these list items inline?

The feeds appear in HTML as follows:

```
<script>
      jQuery(function($) {
        $("#rss-feeds").rss("http://www.feed43.com/channelfireball.xml", {
          limit: 15
       })
</script>



<div style="border:none;width:100%;height:auto;overflow-y:scroll;
overflow-x:scroll;">
      <div class="span2 item">
          <div class="item-wrap">
              <div class="post_results" id="rss-feeds"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try applying style: ul { display: inline-block; }

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've attempted to add this in as many ways and places as I could find. I am able to add some styles to the dynamically created HTML, but have been unable to add this change to the list. If it helps, I am able to change the tags in my JavaScript to anything and achieve the same results. For instance, I could use <water></water> instead of <ul></ul> and get the same output on my webpage.

Comment: have you tried adding the styles as you create the `layoutTemplate`, using the `style` attribute to apply the styles that Robert suggests? adding inline-styles may cause problems down the line with style inheritance though.

Comment: Can you provide mode code? it is not really clear. Thanks

Comment: I updated my post to show the code I am currently using in my RSS reader.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make div elements display inline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224602/how-do-you-make-div-elements-display-inline)