# Display child div inline with parent div content

Tags: css

I have a simple `<div>` structure as follows

```
<div>
    <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
    <div>
        <i class="fa fa-gear display-this-inline"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have the font awesome icon display directly to the right of the link contents.  How is this most easily achieved?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fja9t5ee/)

EDIT: I do not have control over the inner div, the real world issue is much more complicated and I have simplified it here.  The inner div is required.

Comment: Down voting without a reason is not needed, believe it or not there are situations where a programmer does not have control over the mark up and must use CSS to make things work.

Comment: True...usually it's in an f'd up environment where they don't trust people to correct poor code. Not your fault.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224602/how-do-you-make-div-elements-display-inline

Comment: Those were not nested div's however the solution is similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the containing `<div>`:

```
<div>
    <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
    <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fja9t5ee/1/)

Or, if you can't alter the markup that you currently have:

```
a + div{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The best approach would be to assign a more specific selector (class or id) to the anchor or div.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fja9t5ee/4/)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have control over the inner `<div>` tag.

Comment: I have specific classes to use on the anchor, I omitted them for the sake of simplicity.  Thank you the second option will work just fine, you truly are a fancy monkey.  Loved your books as a child!

Comment: Glad to have helped. I appreciate that, it's not everyday somebody calls you a fancy monkey (:

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the containing div as suggested by George.

You can even go a step further.

```
<div>
    <a href="www.google.com">Google <i class="fa fa-gear display-this-inline"></i></a>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fja9t5ee/2/)

Answer (score 0):

use `float: left`

```css
.display-this-inline{
    font-size:20px;
    display:inline;
}

a{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
    <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
    <div>
        <i class="fa fa-gear display-this-inline"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```