# How do I display div inline?

Tags: html

```
<div style='float:left; width:300px; overflow:hidden;'>
   <div style='float:left; width:100px; '>1</div>
   <div style='float:left; width:100px; '>2</div>
   <div style='float:left; width:100px; '>3</div>
   <div style='float:left; width:100px; '>4</div>
</div>
```

I need to display 'div' inline another 'div'. I have some difficulties with css style display:inline-block. Outer 'div' should have some width. div inside have to display inline. In example last 'div' should be invisible, but stay inline with other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make div elements display inline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224602/how-do-you-make-div-elements-display-inline)

Comment: can you post the current css code you are using? Can't tell what's wrong without the styling.

Comment: @darien did you tried with  `style="display: inline"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this CSS on your wrapper div

```
.container{
    overflow: auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

& take out `float` and use `inline-block` instead.

```
 div{
       display: inline-block;  
    }
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/xwJNKV/)

Now you have an inline horizontal scroll!

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    ul#display-inline-block-example,
    ul#display-inline-block-example li {
        /* Setting a common base */                
        margin: 0px;
                padding:0px;
    }

    ul#display-inline-block-example li {
        display: inline-block;
        min-height: 100px;
        background: #ccc;
    }

</style>

<div style='width: 200px; overflow:hidden;'>
<ul id="display-inline-block-example" style='width:350px; height:100px;'>
    <li><div style='width:100px;'>1</div></li>
    <li><div style='width:100px;'>2</div></li>
    <li><div style='width:100px;'>3</div></li>
</ul>
</div>
```