# html class doesn't stay inline

Tags: html, css

Why doesn't the div stay in line rather like this:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="NovosProdutos">
    <div id="name">
        <h1>Novos produtos</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="produtos">
        <div class="product"><h1>product 1</h1></div>
        <div class="product"><h1>product 2</h1></div>
        <div class="product"><h1>product 3</h1></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#name {
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 8px;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-color: #38c23d;
    border-width: 0px 0px 2.5px;
}

#produtos {
    height: 190px;
}

.product {
    width:162.5px;
    height: 155px;
}
```

Is there any problem with the class?

Comment: try using dysplay:inline-block on .product.
but i think you want something like overflow:auto on #produtos.

Comment: @shadownrun `dysplay`? I think you meant `display`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div>` by it's nature goes to the next line and don't stack next to each other

However you can add

```
float:left;
```

to your products class.

example:
http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/OXYPja

Answer (score 0):

By default, the display presentation style for a `<div>` is `block`. You may want to use something that displays `inline`, or set that property for the given `<div>`s in your CSS. See: [How do you make div elements display inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224602/how-do-you-make-div-elements-display-inline)