# what happens when inline and float are applied to element

Tags: html

we cannot set the width and height property to an inline element, i agree. But with the inline element if i add the float property. The width and height of inline element is getting accepted. How is this possible?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>

<style>
.city {
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
color: black;
max-width: 300px;
background-color: aqua;
display: inline;
float: left;
</style>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Responsive <b>Web Design</b> Demo</h1>
<div class="city test">
 <p>It is the center of the Greater Tokyo Area,  and the most populous metropolitan area in the world.</p>
</div>

<div class="city test">
  <p>New York is an important center for international diplomacy and has ncial capital of the world.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your float declaration comes after the display declaration, so float takes precedence. Second, the display: inline declaration is redundant because floating the divs will line them up inline.

Comment: The order of declarations doesn't matter. If the float declaration came *before* the display declaration, the float declaration would still "take precedence". The display: inline declaration is redundant not because floating will line divs up inline, but because floats *cannot* be laid inline. The term "inline" has a very specific definition in CSS.

Comment: "The display: inline declaration is redundant not because floating will line divs up inline, but because floats cannot be laid inline" could you rephrase the sentence. I cannot get what do you say?

Comment: Using `float:left` on each `div` will line up the `div`s horizontally on the same line in the same way that `display:inline` does on elements and treats each `div` as a block (thus you can get width/height). The first `div` with `float:left` will appear all the way to the left, the second will appear immediately to the right of the first, and so on.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224602/how-do-you-make-div-elements-display-inline]Make DIV elements display inline