# Button and ceneterd text in one line

Tags: html

How can I make button to be on the left and a text to be in the center? They should be in one line. I tired this:

```html
<html>
  <body>
      <div style="display: inline"><a href="/back" class="btn btn-default pull-left" role="button">Back</a></div>
      <div style="display: inline"><center><h1>Welcome</h1></center></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But button is above the text.

Comment: Why are you still using the `center` element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make div elements display inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224602/how-do-you-make-div-elements-display-inline)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **`flex` container** to center elements:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  display: inline;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <button>
Back
</button>
  <h1>
    Welcome
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give margin-top to 20px; or something

```
<a href="/back" class="btn btn-default pull-left" role="button" style="margin- 
top:20px;">Back</a>
<center><h1>Welcome</h1></center>
```