# How to display buttons in a horizontal row?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQL1a.jpg)

I want to get the buttons aligned like the attached image but however, on executing the code, I am getting [Output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxW6e.jpg), where the buttons are below one another. 
I have attached the HTML, CSS and JS code. I am new to UI design and so I am failing to find out the error in the CSS code.
I shall be very grateful if anyone suggests me how can I get the Desired Output.

```js
$('.form').find('input').on('keyup blur focus', function (e) {
  
  var $this = $(this),
      label = $this.prev('label');

   if (e.type === 'keyup') {
   if ($this.val() === '') {
          label.removeClass('active highlight');
        } else {
          label.addClass('active highlight');
        }
    } else if (e.type === 'blur') {
     if( $this.val() === '' ) {
      label.removeClass('active highlight'); 
   } else {
      label.removeClass('highlight');   
   }   
    } else if (e.type === 'focus') {
      
      if( $this.val() === '' ) {
      label.removeClass('highlight'); 
   } 
      else if( $this.val() !== '' ) {
      label.addClass('highlight');
   }
    }

});

$('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {
  
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
  
  target = $(this).attr('href');

  $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();
  
  $(target).fadeIn(600);
  
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}


body {
  background:url(../background.jpg);
  /*font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;*/
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-size:cover;
}
.user{
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
border-radius: 50%;
position: relative;
top: -10px;
left: calc(50%-50px);
right: -170px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #040675;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
a:hover {
  color: #179b77;
}

.form {
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3);
  transition: .5s ease;
  position: relative;
  
}

.form:hover {
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 16px rgba(18,18,18,1.00);
 }

.tab-group {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 5px 20px 0;
}
.tab-group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.tab-group li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #0C0E67;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
.tab-group li a:hover {
  background: #0C0E67;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.tab-group .active a {
  background:#1316FA;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-content > div:last-child {
  display:none;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
}

/*label {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(6px);
  left: 13px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 22px;
}
label .req {
  margin: 2px;
  color: red;
}*/

label.active {
  transform: translateY(50px);
  left: 2px;
  font-size: 0px;
}
label.active .req {
  opacity: 0;
}

label.highlight {
  color: #000;
  margin-top:-10px;
}

/*input[type="radio"] {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;

  }*/

input[type="text"],input[type="email"],input[type="tel"],input [type="password"] {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
}
input:focus{
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #000;
}

.field-wrap input{
  padding-left: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 28px;
}

.field-wrap i{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: -5px;
  padding: 9px 8px;
  color: silver;
}
.field-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  
}

.top-row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.top-row > div {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 4%;
}
.top-row > div:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}


.button {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 50rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  background: rgb(54, 57, 221);
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.button:hover, .button:focus {
  background: #1316FA;
}

.bday,
.form-gender{
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 20px;
color: #fff;
}
.button-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.forgot {
  margin-top: -20px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
fieldset.date { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  padding-left: 20px; 
  padding-bottom: .5em; 
  display: block; 
  border: none; 
} 
fieldset.date legend { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  margin-top: .25em; 
  font-size: 100%; 
} 


fieldset.date label { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: -20em; 
  left: -200em; 
} 

fieldset.date select { 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
font-size: 100%; 
display: inline; 
} 

.birth{
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 34px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

#check1{
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
#check2{
  color: #fff;
}

.footer{
  position: relative;
 /* width: 70%
  padding-left: 180px;*/
  text-align: right;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.footer> div.social{
position: relative;
float: right;
color:#fff;
font-size:19px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.footer i{
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height:40px;
  left:0px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: rgb(0,0,0,0);
  text-align: center;
}

.footer.facebook{
  background: #3b5999;
}

.footer.linkedin{
  background: #0077B5;
}

.footer.google{
  background: #dd4b39;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form">
      
      <ul class="tab-group">
        <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
      </ul>
      
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="signup">   
        
          <form action="" method="post">
          
         
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required autocomplete="off" />
              <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
            </div>
        
            
          <div class="field-wrap">
              
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required autocomplete="off"/>
            <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            
            <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required autocomplete="off"/>
            <i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
          </div>
          
          

          <div class="field-wrap">
              <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone" required autocomplete="off"/>
              <i class="fa fa-phone icon"></i>
            </div>
          
            <div class="field-wrap">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Post Code" pattern="[0-9]{5}" required autocomplete="off"/>
                <i class="fa fa-map-marker icon"></i>
              </div>

              <div class="bday">
                  <labe>
                      Birthday<br>
                    </label>
                    <select name="DoBday" class="birth">
                        <option >Month</option>
                        <option value="1"> 1 </option>
                        <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                        <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                        
                  </select>
                  <select name="DoBMonth" class="birth">
                      <option >Day</option>
                      <option value="January"> January </option>
                      <option value="February"> February </option>
                      <option value="March"> March </option>
                      
                  </select>
                  
                      <select name="DoByear" class="birth">
                              <option>Year</option>
                              <option value="2000"> 2000 </option>
                              <option value="1990"> 1990 </option>
                              <option value="1991"> 1991 </option>
                              
                       </select>
              </div>

              <div class="form-gender">
                  <span id="gend">
                          Gender<br>
                   </span>
                  <input type="radio" name="male" value="male" id="" checked> Male &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                  <input type="radio" name="male" value="female" id=""> Female &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                  <input type="radio" name="male" value="other" id=""> Other
              </div>

              <div class="field-wrap">
                  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required autocomplete="off"/>
                  <i class="fa fa-lock icon"></i>
                </div>

              <div class="field-wrap">
                 <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required autocomplete="off"/>
                  <i class="fa fa-lock icon"></i>
              </div>
              <div id="check1">
                  <input type="checkbox"  id="chk1"> I accept the <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms </a>and <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Conditions</a>
              </div>
          <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Register </button>
          
          </form>

        </div>
        
        <div id="login">   
      
         <img src="./user.png" class="user">
          
          <form action="/" method="post">
          
           <div class="field-wrap">
            
            <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required autocomplete="off"/>
            <i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
          </div>
          
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required autocomplete="off"/>
            <i class="fa fa-lock icon"></i>
          </div>
          <div id="check2">
              <input type="checkbox"  id="chk2"> Remember Me
          </div>
          <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
          
          <button class="button button-block"/>Log In</button>
          <!--<div class="span">
            <span>OR</span>
          </div>-->
          <div class="footer">
            OR Login With
            <div class="social-facebook">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="social-linkedin">
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="social-google">
                <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          </form>

        </div>
        
      </div><!-- tab-content -->
      
</div> <!-- /form -->
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please try and shorten the code to a minimum. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Applied that and it worked! Thank you :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make div elements display inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224602/how-do-you-make-div-elements-display-inline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve expected result , use below option of display: inline-block for footer divs

```
.footer > div{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/bQLYPM

**Issue**: div is block level element by default hence it is displaying footer divs in separate line