# How to hide and display inline element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a inline element. I am trying to hide and show it using button. But when I click `document.getElementById('').style.display = 'inline';` I'm getting block elements. How to get the element inline as it was set before.
my code looks like;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
          #mydata{
            display:none;
            font-size: 25;
          }
        .chartCard {
            width: 100vw;
            height: calc(90vh - 100px);
            background: rgb(133, 43, 43);
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
          }
          .chartBox {
            width: 650px;
            padding: 8px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            margin: 1px 22px;
            border: solid 3px rgba(255, 26, 104, 1);
            background: white;
          }
          .button:hover{
            background-color: #005201;
            color: rgb(255, 253, 250);;
        }
            .button {
                background-color: rgb(69, 9, 188);
                border: none;
                color: white;
                padding: 16px 32px;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 20px;
                margin: 2px 2px;
                transition-duration: 0.4s;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
    </style>
    <script>
        function changedata(parameter){
            if(parameter==0){
                document.getElementById('myreport').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('mydata').style.display = 'block';
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('mydata').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('myreport').style.display = 'inline';
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="button" onclick="changedata(1)">Myreport</button>
    <button class="button" onclick="changedata(0)">Mydata</button>
    <div id="mydata">
        <h1>This is my Report</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="chartCard" id="myreport">
        <div class="chartBox">
            <p>Ram</p>
        </div>
        <div class="chartBox">
            <p>Shyam</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, as you can see as I click button, inline element are getting converted to block element. how to resolve it. looking for your help. Thanks in advance

Comment: The display property is `flex` before you are changing it to `inline`. So the element’s children will change to `block` instead of `flex-item`.

Comment: Please refer to this thread for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/224626/11242070

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `display:flex` so you have to set it back.
Also, you don't need js to hide or show your sections, you can use `:target`.

```css
.menu{
  display:flex;
}
a{
  margin-right:20px;
}
.section{
  padding:20px;
  width:fit-content;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:none;
}
.section:target{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#a">go to A</a>
  <a href="#b">go to B</a>
  <a href="#c">go to C</a>
</div>
<br>
<div id="a" class="section">Section A</div>
<div id="b" class="section">Section B</div>
<div id="c" class="section">Section C</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your function to set display to `flex` for `myreport`, initially you have set `display:flex` for `.chartCard`

```
   function changedata(parameter) {
     if (parameter == 0) {
       document.getElementById('myreport').style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById('mydata').style.display = 'block';
     } else {
       document.getElementById('mydata').style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById('myreport').style.display = 'flex';
     }
   }
```

fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/fhps08re/

Answer (score 1):

when you click on button, your 'myreport' element get display: 'inline'. it's work correct. because your elements with 'chartBox' class is div and div has display: block in its default css, the elements shows in two line.

use this to correct :
when you click the button, instead of set display to inline, set display to flex. as you do this in your css.

```
function changedata(parameter){
            if(parameter==0){
                document.getElementById('myreport').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('mydata').style.display = 'block';
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('mydata').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('myreport').style.display = 'flex';
            }
        }
```

or you can use span instead of div with class: 'chartBox'